# Joining on long text field

Tags: mysql, performance, join, stored-procedures

I am building a database and have run into an issue where two tables need to be joined via an error message field, currently set to varchar(255). This (obviously) causes performance and locking issues when the join is performed. My initial statement was hanging on any update larger than 1000 rows. Here is the code:

```
    UPDATE Integration_Detail D
    JOIN Integration_Error_Descriptor E
    ON D.Error_Message = E.Error_Message
    SET D.Error_Key = E.Error_Key
    WHERE D.Error_Key is null;
```

I decided to change to a stored procedure in order to break the UPDATE statement down into smaller pieces. This works, but is not ideal in terms of performance since I am using a while loop and updating in batches of 200. The procedure code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_detail_table()

BEGIN

declare rowsToProcess int default 0;

set rowsToProcess = 
    (select count(*)
    from Integration_Report.Integration_Detail
    where Error_Key is null);

CREATE TABLE Integration_Report.temp_error_processing (
    Detail_Key bigint DEFAULT null,
    Error_Key bigint DEFAULT null
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

while rowsToProcess > 0 DO

    INSERT INTO Integration_Report.temp_error_processing
        (SELECT D.Detail_Key, E.Error_Key
            FROM Integration_Report.Integration_Detail D
            JOIN Integration_Report.Integration_Error_Descriptor E
            ON D.Error_Message = E.Error_Message
            WHERE D.Error_Key is null
            ORDER BY D.Insert_Datetime desc
            LIMIT 200);

    UPDATE Integration_Report.Integration_Detail D
    JOIN Integration_Report.temp_error_processing T
    ON D.Detail_Key = T.Detail_Key
    SET D.Error_Key = T.Error_Key;

    TRUNCATE TABLE Integration_Report.temp_error_processing;

    set rowsToProcess = 
        (select count(*)
        from Integration_Report.Integration_Detail
        where Error_Key is null);

end while;

drop table Integration_Report.temp_error_processing;

END;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this that is faster and uses less memory? I have not written many procedures before so please let me know if my code is ugly as well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there an index on the error message field?

Comment: Yes, I indexed the field. It helped a bit, but causes new inserts to the Details table to run slowly due to the size of the index, so I'm hoping it can be removed eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the inefficiency of the chunking you have is that it is repeatedly stepping over finished rows.  The goal is to look at a different 200 rows each time.

I discuss details here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Note that it walks through the table using the `PRIMARY KEY` in order to avoid re-scans.  And it is not necessarily processing a full chunksize each time.  And there is no need for the `COUNT(*)`, since reaching the end of the table is sufficient for termination.

Comment: Thanks. The documentation you provided helped and performance has increased significantly.